# How to identify/verify full integration points in the perforce history

Tags: perforce

In an analysis of the history in our perforce depot, I need to identify those changes where a full integration from another branch was performed and also find out the exact change number of the source of that integration. Unfortunately, even though such a full integration is a common operation, I could not find any easy and reliable way to detect it in the history. Please let me know if I missed something.

In any case: via a set of scripts using 'p4 filelog' and matching up revision numbers, I managed to find all candidate changes and their respective integration source change. What I am missing is a means to distinguish full integrations from cherry-picks or partial integrations limited to a subdirectory. For this, the closest I could find is the 'p4 interchanges' command, which does exactly the thing I need, except for the problem that the 'toFile' argument cannot have an '@' revision specification.

I would have hoped that

```
p4 interchanges //depot/sourcebranch@123400 //depot/targetbranch@123499
```

would tell me whether any changes were missing in the integration point I found, but it only gives the error 'A revision specification (# or @) cannot be used here.' - which matches the documentation.

Is there any other means to examine integration points in the p4 history to distinguish cherry-picks from full merges?

Answer (score 1):

Use the undoc `p4 integ -C changelist` command:

```
p4 integrate -1 -2 -C changelist# -Rlou -Znnn
    ...  The -C
    changelist# flag considers only integration history from changelists
    at or below the given number, allowing you to ignore credit from
    subsequent integrations.  ...
```

Hence:

```
p4 integ -n -C 123499 //depot/sourcebranch/...@123400 //depot/targetbranch/...
```

should tell you whether sourcebranch@123400 was fully integrated into targetbranch@123499.  If you use `-C 123498` in theory the difference in the output will show you which files were integrated.

There are probably some edge cases around deleted files -- e.g. if you integrate a deleted file into a file that's deleted at the head revision, it will report "up to date" regardless of integration history, so I can imagine that a file that was skipped for that reason but then subsequently re-added might give a false positive with the above method.  (Or it might not -- I have vague memories of possibly fixing that scenario, but undoc bug fixes don't show up in the relnotes...)

Here's an example where foo@2 was integrated into bar@3:

```
sams-mbp:test samwise$ p4 filelog ...
//stream/main/test/bar
... #2 change 4 delete on 2019/07/21 by samwise@samwise-dvcs-1517552832 (text) 'delete'
... #1 change 3 branch on 2019/07/21 by samwise@samwise-dvcs-1517552832 (text) 'branch'
... ... branch from //stream/main/test/foo#1
//stream/main/test/foo
... #2 change 6 edit on 2019/07/21 by samwise@samwise-dvcs-1517552832 (text) 'edit'
... #1 change 2 add on 2019/07/21 by samwise@samwise-dvcs-1517552832 (text) 'add'
... ... branch into //stream/main/test/bar#1


sams-mbp:test samwise$ p4 integ -n -C 2 foo@2 bar
//stream/main/test/bar#2 - branch/sync from //stream/main/test/foo#1
sams-mbp:test samwise$ p4 integ -n -C 3 foo@2 bar
foo@2 - all revision(s) already integrated.
```

With `-C 2` (before the branch), we see a replay of the integration as it would have happened as of that point in time.  With `-C 3` (the changelist of the branch), we see "all revisions integrated" because by that point in time it had already happened.

Comment: I don't quite get how that would work. In my understanding, 'p4 integrate' affects the current workspace setting everything up to submit the integration. How would it set up the workspace for this 'hypothetical' integration?

In any case - the solution that I found myself works fine for me. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Sorry, should have made explicit that the idea is to use `-n` to do a report/preview, not to actually open files and submit a integration (since you're trying to do a report, not actually integrate something).  This is essentially a simulation of what would have happened if somebody ran an integrate right after change 123499 was submitted.  If it reports "up to date", then everything was up to date as of that point in time (which is the question you're asking).  If not, not.

Comment: Indeed, it does work. Results are similar to my own method, except in corner cases, where "p4 integrate -C" sometimes claims missing integrations when "p4 interchanges" claims that all changes are integrated. Checking just two sample cases, I found that each solution was wrong in one situation. Ugly, but I don't have the time to dig in any further. In my case, false positives are worse, so I'll have to go with the 'p4 integrate -C' approach.

Comment: By now, I can confirm that there are false positives: In many cases, points where a new, complete branch was created, 'p4 integ -n -C' reports missing integrations for files that had been created and lateron deleted before the branching point. These files correctly don't show up at all on the new branch, but 'p4 integ -n -C' still reports these integrations as pending.

Comment: More false positives: for files that were added on the original branch, then correctly branched to the target and later on deleted on the target branch, the 'add' shows up as missing integration at the branching point. Unfortunately, our history has >10000 of integration points and for >1000 of them, 'p4 integ -n -C' gives suspicious results. Digging into a few individual cases, each of them turns out to be another edge case related to deleted files in some way.

Comment: That last one sounds wrong.  Are you sure you're passing the changelist of the integration itself (on the target, NOT the source of the integration) via `-C`?

Comment: I added a simple example that covers the exact scenario you're talking about and shows it working.

Answer (score 0):

After continuing to try out all combinations of arguments, I finally found a solution that works for me:

```
p4 interchanges -b SOURCE_to_TARGET //depot/targetbranch/...@targetchange
```

will print out all changes on the source branch that are missing on targetbranch@targetchange. It will return only changes older than targetchange. If this list contains no changes older than sourcechange, the targetchange was a full integration.

The command may take considerable time to complete when the returned list is long. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to truncate this search, but I can live with that.

As it seems, some of this functionality was buggy up to server version 2018.2 which might have caused difficulties in my earlier attempts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't actually work -- the `@targetchange` arg is being applied to the source of the integration.  My guess is that you have a particular test case where this technique happens to return the correct result (i.e. it will tend to "work" most of the time if the source and target changes are sufficiently close together) but it won't do the right thing in the general case.

Comment: So far, this command works fine for a large set of sample cases throughout the long history of our project. The @targetchange argument is definitely applied to the target of the integration. To what I observe, the documentation of interchanges (in server version 2019.1) is actually correct: Variant 1 (without -b) applies the revRange to the source while variant 2 (with -b) applies it to the target.

Comment: I don't see any changes in the relnotes to indicate it works any differently in 2019.1 than it has in the previous ~40 releases -- but if it works, great!